# Stata command line arguments in batch mode

Tags: arguments, batch-processing, stata

A [helpful FAQ from Stata](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/passing-arguments-to-do-files/index.html) describes that arguments can be passed to `do` files.  My `do` file looks like this:

```
* program.do : Program to fetch information from main dataset
args inname outname

save `outname', emptyok // file to hold results
insheet using `inname', comma clear names case

// a bunch of processing

save `outname', replace
```

According to the FAQ, this script can be run using `do filename.csv result.dta`.  When I run this command from within Stata, everything works fine.  The program is long, however, so I want to run it in batch mode.  Stata has [another FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/unix/batch-mode/index.html) about batch mode.

Combining the information from these webpages, I type the following at my Unix prompt:

```
$ nohup stata -b do program.do filename.csv result.dta &
```

Stata starts up, but it terminates with the following error:

```
. save `outname', emptyok // file to hold results
invalid file specification
r(198);
```

A little experimentation tells me that Stata is never receiving the two arguments when I run the program in batch mode.  What is the solution to this problem? (i.e. how do you pass arguments to a do file when running it in batch mode?)

Comment: It appears that you can't do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thread below may be helpful:

http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-09/msg00609.html

In Windows, if my program `Test.do` is:

```
args a b
display "`a'" 
display "`b'"
```

I can run it in batch mode in Windows by simply typing:

`"c:\Stata13\stata.exe" /e do "c:\Scripts\Test.do" Test Script`

And it will display (within Stata):

`Test`

`Script`

So I wonder whether the `nohup` is what's preventing your program from working.