# logging in Stata batch mode

Tags: batch-file, stata

### Nice

I use Windows batch files to execute various Stata do-files in a certain order. For example, when I do

```
StataMP-64 /e do myDoFile1.do
StataMP-64 /e do myDoFile2.do
```

Stata executes `myDoFile1.do` and nicely routes its output to `myDoFile1.log`, and then executes `myDoFile2.do` and routes its output to `myDoFile2.log`. By the way, both log files are in the same directory as the do-files.

### Not nice

Now I want to pass an argument for each of these do-file. In particular, this argument is a directory path. For example,

```
StataMP-64 /e do myDoFile1.do "C:\MyDir"
StataMP-64 /e do myDoFile2.do "C:\MyDir"
```

Now Stata executes `myDoFile1.do` as expected, but saves its output to a file named `MyDir.log`. And it does the same to `myDoFile2.do`, overwriting the log for `myDoFile1.do`.

### Questions:

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. How to solve this, and have outputs routed to `myDoFile1.log` and `myDoFile2.do` respectively, preferably without the need to explicitly starting to log in each do file?

### Edit 1:

Just to add to this problem, I tested the case in which I need to pass 2 directory paths to my do-file, like so

```
StataMP-64 /e do myDoFile1.do "C:\MyDir1" "C:\MyDir2"
```

The output is now routed to a file named `MyDir2.log`. Strange.

### Edit 2:

I reproduced the example in Roberto's answer below. Here's the screenshot to show that the problem is indeed occurring. I use both a Windows batch file and the Windows prompt (which Roberto used in answer below), and I reproduced the problem either way. I am using Stata 13 MP on Windows 7.[image]

### Edit 3:

I've also replicated this on Stata 12 SE, Windows 7.

Comment: The same question is asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253890/stata-command-line-arguments-in-batch-mode), with the exception that the OS of interest is Linux.

Comment: very different questions, I'm afraid. in that question, OP was having a problem with his code breaking -- probably due to incorrect syntax. my question is about the file name to which output is printed.

Comment: If you get no answer here, try statalist.com. (Please follow the guidelines stated in the FAQ.) If no solution there, then there's tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping double quotes seems to solve the issue:

```
StataMP-64 /e do myDoFile1.do \"C:\MyDir\"
```

So it seems that Windows (7) is stripping the quotes before passing the arguments to Stata.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult for me to post text at the moment, so I'm attaching an image. It shows that it works fine for me. One argument (a complete directory path) is given and it shows up as a local macro. Moreover, the log file is created in the expected place, with the expected name.

[image]

The image shows all windows and files involved in the process.

That's Stata 12.0 on MS Windows XP.

(You can right-click on the image and download/view it at a greater resolution.)