# Stata command not found in batch mode

Tags: macos, zsh, stata, macos-catalina

I'm trying to run a Stata .do file in batch mode according to the instructions [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/mac/advanced-topics/).

However, `Stata -b testdo.do` yields:

```
zsh: command not found: Stata
```

Replacing `Stata` with `StataMP` yields similar results.

My suspicion is that this is a path issue, but my `.zshrc` file includes the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH/Applications/Stata/StataMP.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

and `echo $PATH` confirms that the path to Stata is indeed in the `$PATH` variable:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/arthurmorris/anaconda3/bin:/Users/arthurmorris/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin/Applications/Stata/StataMP.app/Contents/MacOS
```

My issue appears to be distinct from: [Stata command line arguments in batch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253890/stata-command-line-arguments-in-batch-mode)

I'm using Stata MP 16, in macOS Catalina 10.15.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The export statement was missing `:` and thus the portion of `$PATH` that pointed to Stata was not properly delimited from the other entries in `$PATH`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Stata/StataMP.app/Contents/MacOS/
```