# stata-se, xstata-se command not found

Tags: macos, ubuntu, stata, x11

I can't open the GUI of Stata running on local macOS machine from remote Ubuntu server.

I have installed `stata-se` on my local machine, I can open X11 apps like `xclock` and `xeyes`. I'm using the following command to connect to the server:

```
ssh -X username@servername -p XXXX
```

Is there any to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Since the distinction is a little unclear in the question:

According to the [documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/gsu.pdf#gsu) the command to launch the Stata SE GUI is:

```sh
xstata-se
```

while

```sh
stata-se
```

launches the console version.

Since these are not working you can confirm the syntax diagram with:

```sh
stata -h
```

which will tell you the correct syntax, if Stata is actually installed.

If you are seeing something like:

```sh
$ command not found: Stata
```

then you may, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650805/stata-command-not-found-in-batch-mode/62651002#62651002), need to make sure that the path to Stata is properly set in your path file. Exactly how you do this depends on your terminal and operating system.

Comment: @MarwadiVirinche Great! Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark near the up/down arrows if it worked for you.